# Java Swing how to link MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am currently creating a program using Swing and Model-View-Controller. However, I am having difficulty understanding how to link all the classes together. I keep getting various errors such as BasicView cannot find Controller and the constructor in BasicController doesn't work. I have copied below my attempt, if anyone would be able to fix it for me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

MODEL:

```
public class BasicModel {
    private JFrame frame;
    public BasicModel() {
    }
public String calculation(String label){
...
}
```

VIEW:

```
public class BasicView {
    BasicController control = new BasicController();
    private JFrame frame;
    public BasicView() {
   // gui elements
    ActionListener button_eqListener = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            label2.setText(controller.getCalculation(label.getText()));
            label.setText("");
        }
    };  
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public class BasicController {
    private BasicView view;
    private BasicModel model;

    public BasicController(BasicView view, BasicModel model){
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    } 

    public String getCalculation(String label){
        return model.calculation(splitLabel(label));
    }
}
```

MVC MAIN PROGRAM:

```
public class BasicMVC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicModel model = new BasicModel();
        BasicView view = new BasicView();
        BasicController controller = new BasicController(model,view);
        BasicView.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: how much knowledge do you have in Java? Is this your first try? What means _" the constructor in BasicController doesn't work"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

> MVC MAIN PROGRAM:
>
> ```
> public class BasicMVC {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         BasicModel model = new BasicModel();
>         BasicView view = new BasicView();
>         BasicController controller = new BasicController(model,view);
>         BasicView.setVisible(true);
>     }
> }
> ```

I think you got it wrong:

#### Model

The Model does not know about the other two components (what you did right) and is merily a bunch of DTOs without any sophisticated logic so I would not expect the `calculation` method there.

#### Controller

the Controller contains the business logic working on the model data. therefore the controller needs to know the Model. But is doesn not need to know the View. This is what you did wrong.

#### View

The view binds the output and the user input with the data in the model and the business actions in the controller, therefore it needs to know both, the Model and the Controller (what you did wrong too)

In case the View needs to display some results from the controller you should use return values at the controller methods or implement the *listener* pattern to get (intermediate) results out of the controller. Also the controller could (and should) interact via the model with the view.

### edit

> Can you please help me rearrange everything please?

this is my suggestion:

#### Model

```
public class BasicModel {
    private final IntegerProperty someModelData = new SimpleIntergerProperty(0);
    public BasicModel() {
    }

   public IntegerProperty someModelDataProperty(){
     return someModelData;
   }

   public void setSomeModelData(inf newVal){
     someModelData.set(newVal);
   }    
}
```

#### Controller

```
public class BasicController {
    private BasicModel model;

    public BasicController(BasicModel model){
        this.model = model;
    } 

    public void calculate(int someInput){
        model.setSomeModelDAta(someComplicatedCalculationOn(someInput));
    }
 //  
}
```

#### View

```
public class BasicView {
    private final BasicController control;
    private final BasicModel model;
    private final JFrame frame ;
    private final JTextFiled input = new JTextFiled();
    private final JLabel output = new JLabel();

    public BasicView(BasicController controller, BasicModel model, JFrame frame) {
      this.frame=frame;
      this.control= controller;
      this.model=model;
      model.someModelDataProperty().addListener(property, oldVal, newVal -> {
        output.setText("Value has changed from "+oldVal+" to " newVal);
      } 
   // gui elements
    ActionListener button_eqListener = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           controller.calculate(Integer.parseInt(input.getText()));
        }
    };  
}
```

#### main

```
public class BasicMVC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicModel model = new BasicModel();
        BasicController controller = new BasicController(model);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        BasicView view = new BasicView(controller, model, frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

***disclaimer*** all code untested and not compilable!

Comment: Can you please help me rearrange everything please?